# R error: not enough finite observations (Spearman test) / i am literally lost

Tags: r, statistics

I am honestly really struggling, so please please help me!

I am trying to measure the spearman correlation between the two constructs "benefit_individual" and "challenge_individual" but get the error message:

```
Fehler in cor.test.default(benefit_individual, challenge_individual, method = "spearman",  : 
  not enough finite observations
Ruft auf: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> cor.test -> cor.test.default
Zusätzlich: Es gab 50 oder mehr Warnungen (Anzeige der ersten 50 mit warnings())
Ausführung angehalten
```

Can anyone please help me? I have tried literally everything but nothing works. Btw in the dataset, I have used NA for every blank cell.

```
benefit_individual=
  rowMeans(cbind(
    rowMeans(cbind(
      df$v_1_benefit4_important,
      df$v_1_benefit5_important,
      df$v_1_benefit6_important,
      df$v_1_benefit8_important),na.rm=TRUE),
    rowMeans(cbind(
      df$v_2_benefit4_important,
      df$v_2_benefit5_important,
      df$v_2_benefit6_important,
      df$v_2_benefit8_important),na.rm=TRUE)
    ))

challenge_individual = 
  rowMeans(cbind(
    rowMeans(cbind(
      df$v_1_challenge3_important_highInvestment,na.rm=TRUE,
      df$v_1_challenge4_important,na.rm=TRUE,
      df$v_1_challenge5_important,na.rm=TRUE,
      df$v_1_challenge6_important,na.rm=TRUE,
      df$v_1_challenge7_important,na.rm=TRUE),na.rm = TRUE),
    rowMeans(cbind(
      df$v_2_challenge3_important_highInvestment,na.rm=TRUE,
      df$v_2_challenge4_important,na.rm=TRUE,
      df$v_2_challenge5_important,na.rm=TRUE,
      df$v_2_challenge6_important,na.rm=TRUE,
      df$v_2_challenge7_important),na.rm=TRUE)
  ))

#liegt überhaupt ein Zusammenhang vor?
cor.test(benefit_individual,challenge_individual,method="spearman",paired=TRUE,na.rm=TRUE)
#negativer Zusammenhang?
cor.test(benefit_individual,challenge_individual,method="spearman",alternative="less",paired=TRUE,na.rm=TRUE) 
#positiver Zusammenhang?
cor.test(benefit_individual,challenge_individual,method="spearman",alternative="greater",paired=TRUE,na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi akasra, please provide an example of your dataset using `dput()`.

Comment: Try the same function call with made-up data for which you know the result. E.g. same data twice should yield a high correlation value, two sample of independent noise should yield a low value. When you know you can call the function successfully, then go back to your original data. By the way, you can help others help you by saying exactly what are the numbers you are working with, via `dput` as suggested above.